# file mask to exclude *.m.swp files in git

Tags: gitignore

When I run git status, `*.m.swp` files are showing up in the "`untracked list`" because I currently have these files open in MacVim (The originals are MATLAB files with `*.m` file extensions).
I have tried adding `*.m.swp`, and various permutations of this, to my `.gitignore` file so that the files are ignored, but nothing seems to work for me.
See an example of git status output below:

```
git status
# On branch mybranch1
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   ../dir1/file1.m
#   new file:   file2.m
#   new file:   file3.m
#   modified:   file4.m
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ../../dir2/.file5.m.swp
#   ../dir1/.file6.m.swp
#   ../dir1/.file1.m.swp
#   ../dir1/.file7.m.swp
#   ../dir1/.file8.swp
#   .file9.m.swp
#   .file4.m.swp
```

How can I get git to ignore these?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.*.m.swp
```

should work: I have tested it in my msysgit1.7.4 environment.
So: not "`*...`" but "`.*...`".

Don't forget to add your modified `.gitignore` to the index before doing a new `git status`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! I don't think I was adding `.gitignore` before running `git status`.  I have it in my global ignores now.

Comment: @Abbie: excellent :) I take it the `.gitignore` is now working?

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\\.m\\.swp
```

do this instead, since unescaped .'s match anything

Comment: You don't need to escape dots in .gitignore